# Biblatex: How to make a specific \citefield bold?

Tags: biblatex, bold

I have some reference as the following.

```
    @article {RefNumber,
    AUTHOR = {LastName, FirstName},
     TITLE = {ArticleTitle},
   JOURNAL = {JournalName},
    VOLUME = {Vol},
    NUMBER = {No},
     PAGES = {FirstPage--LastPage},
      YEAR = {PubYear},
    }
```

When I call the volume number by `\citefield{RefNumber}{volume}`, I want the *volume* to be in **bold**. I know that `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}` only changes *volume* in the bibliography. How this code should be modified to solve my problem?

Comment: You have to specify `\citefield{RefNumber}[article]{volume}` or in `\citefield{RefNumber}[bold]{volume}`. It seems that `\citefield` does not follow the formatting instructions specific to a entrytype.

Comment: @Guido Your comment is pretty much the answer. `\citefield` applies the `citefield` format when the optional argument isn't provided. In biblatex.def this is defined with `\DeclareFieldFormat{citefield}{#1}`. Use of `\citefield{<key>}[volume]{volume}` would probably make the most sense here.

Comment: @Guido, Audrey: Thank you very much. You both helped me to figure this structure out. I use `\citefield{#1}[article]{volume}`and `\citefield{#1}[article]{number}` now to copy the formatting from the *bibliography*.

Answer (score 5):

You have to specify `\citefield{RefNumber}[article]{volume}` or use `\citefield{RefNumber}[bold]{volume}`.

`\citefield` does not follow the formatting instructions specific to a `entrytype` but it takes the formatting specifications from `citefield` format when the optional argument is not provided.